# sqlite select date from datetime row

Tags: sqlite, datetime

Hi I have a table that have a datetime column like: '2015/01/10 09:58:03'
Is posible select specifying only the date? 
I've tried this but no results:

```
SELECT datetime, value FROM lectures WHERE datetime=DATE('2015/01/10')
SELECT datetime, value FROM lectures WHERE datetime=DATE('2015-01-10')
SELECT datetime, value FROM lectures WHERE datetime='20150110'
```

I Can obtain the required result (values from one day) with this query but no seems too elegant:

```
SELECT datetime, valor_lectura FROM lectures WHERE datetime>'2015/01/10' and datetime<'2015/01/11'
```

Other question: Whats the best method to obtain only the first record or only the last record of the results of a query? At the moment can obtain these sending all results to a table (with language php or python) and obtain the record with table functions.

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT datetime, valor_lectura FROM lectures WHERE datetime LIKE '2015/08/12%'
```

this will find all values that start with 2015/08/12.

if you do like this:

```
SELECT datetime, valor_lectura 
FROM lectures 
WHERE datetime LIKE '2015/08/12%'
ORDER BY datetime ASC|DESC
LIMIT 1
```

you'll have the smallest or the biggest date according to the ASC or DESC keyword that you have used (you have to use only one!)

Comment: Runs perfectly JoulinRouge, many thanks!!! To obtain obtain only the first record or only the last record of the results of a query the best method is ORDER BY and then LIMIT.